# Tidyverse and R: how to count rows in a tibble of a nested dataframe

Tags: r, oop, tidyverse, tibble

So, I've checked multiple posts and haven't found anything.  According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47479283/r-how-to-access-a-tibble-in-a-tibble), my code should work, but it isn't.

Objective:  I want to essentially print out the number of subjects--which in this case is also the number of rows in this tibble.

**Code:**

```
 data<-read.csv("advanced_r_programming/data/MIE.csv")

make_LD<-function(x){
  LongitudinalData<-x%>%
    group_by(id)%>%
    nest()
  structure(list(LongitudinalData), class = "LongitudinalData")
}

print.LongitudinalData<-function(x){
  paste("Longitudinal dataset with", x[["id"]], "subjects")

}

x<-make_LD(data)

print(x)
```

**Here's the head of the dataset I'm working on:**

```
> head(x)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 10 x 2
      id                  data
   <int>                <list>
 1    14 <tibble [11,945 x 4]>
 2    20 <tibble [11,497 x 4]>
 3    41 <tibble [11,636 x 4]>
 4    44 <tibble [13,104 x 4]>
 5    46 <tibble [13,812 x 4]>
 6    54 <tibble [10,944 x 4]>
 7    64 <tibble [11,367 x 4]>
 8    74 <tibble [11,517 x 4]>
 9   104 <tibble [11,232 x 4]>
10   106 <tibble [13,823 x 4]>
```

**Output:**

```
[1] "Longitudinal dataset with  subjects"
```

I've tried every possible combination from the aforementioned stackoverflow post and none seem to work.

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the dataset

Comment: Although I used the head function, the dataset is shown in its entirety.

Answer (score 5):

Here are two options:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Create a nested data frame
dat = mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  nest %>% as.tibble
```

> ```
>     cyl               data
> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 10]>
> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>
> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>
> ```

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(nrow=map_dbl(data, nrow))

dat %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(nrow = nrow(data.frame(data)))
```

> ```
>     cyl               data  nrow
> 1     6  <tibble [7 x 10]>     7
> 2     4 <tibble [11 x 10]>    11
> 3     8 <tibble [14 x 10]>    14
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific function for this in the tidyverse: `n()`

You can simply do: `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(rows = n())`

```
> mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(rows = n())
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl  rows
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    11
2     6     7
3     8    14
```

In more sophisticated cases, in which subjects may span across multiple rows ("long format data"), you can do (assuming `hp` denotes the subject):

```
> mtcars %>% group_by(cyl, hp) %>% #always group by subject-ID last
+   summarise(n = n()) %>% #observations per subject and cyl
+   summarise(n = n()) #subjects per cyl (implicitly summarises across all group-variables except the last)
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'cyl'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl     n
  <dbl> <int>
1     4    10
2     6     4
3     8     9
```

Note that the `n` in the last case is smaller than in the first because there are cars with same amount of `cyl` and `hp` that are now counted as just one "subject".